# nginx redirect ignoring slash

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have some URLs that looks like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/stuff/web-design-development

http://www.mywebsite.com/web-design/

http://www.mywebsite.com/web-design/secondary-page

Basically, I need anything from /web-design, with or without slash, and including anything after a slash (like the third URL) redirected to /. But the problem I'm having is that my redirect affects the first URL, because it has "web-design" in it.

Here's what I have:

```
if ($request_filename ~ web-design/.+) {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com permanent;
}
```

Any idea how I can correct this?

Comment: Have you tried `web-design/?.*`

Comment: No, I still get a redirect loop when I go to the first URL.

Answer (score 1):

A simple location block will match all these

```
location /web-design {
  return 301 $scheme://www.mywebsite.com;
end
```

This will match any thing that **starts** with `/web-design` and redirect it.

Here's [why return and not rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites) and here's the [location directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation.

Also keep in mind that 301 responses are cachable, if you are experiencing weird behaviour consider clearing your cache because maybe your browser cached an old 301 when the configuration wasn't correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simplifing my rewrites.

Instead of using if statements, I just did:

```
rewrite ^/web-design/?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ permanent;
```